# Babel, caption — french versus everyone else

Tags: captions, babel

I have a document where we have quotes in several languages, including French, thus we load several languages via `babel`. However, even if French is not the active language, it still affects the caption setup if the `caption` package is loaded.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french,english]{babel}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
fsdf
\caption{d}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Output, notice the `--` instead of the expected `colon` separator.

[image]

Who is to blame here? `babel` or `caption`? (so I can send a bug report)

(BTW: same result on TeXLIve 2017 frozen and TeXLive 2018)

Comment: `babel`. But it seems intended: "In French, captions in figures and tables should never be printed as ‘Figure 1: ’
which is the default in standard LaTeX2e classes (a space should always preceed a colon in French), anyway ‘Figure 1 – ’ is preferred."

Comment: The documentation of `babel-french` says, at the end of section 1.2.3, “When French is not the main language, the colon is preserved for all languages including French”. Bug.

Comment: It can be redefined with `\renewcommand*{\CaptionSeparator}{...}` according to `babel-french`.

Comment: Oh, well, it's mixed responsibility with `caption`: if I remove `\usepackage{caption}`, the colon appears.

Comment: @egreg is correct, of course. I paid no attention to the default language in my comments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The culprit is `caption`; in `caption3.sty` we find

```
\caption@ifundefined\FB@makecaption{}{%
  \caption@CheckCommand\@makecaption{%
    % frenchb.ldf [2005/02/06 v1.6g French support from the babel system]
    % frenchb.ldf [2007/10/05 v2.0e French support from the babel system]
    \long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
      \vskip\abovecaptionskip
      \sbox\@tempboxa{#1\CaptionSeparator #2}%
      \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize
        #1\CaptionSeparator #2\par
      \else
        \global \@minipagefalse
        \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
      \fi
      \vskip\belowcaptionskip}}
  \ifx\@makecaption\STD@makecaption
    \DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{default}{\CaptionSeparator}
    \def\caption@frenchb{% supress frenchb warning
      \let\STD@makecaption\@makecaption
      \let\FB@makecaption\@makecaption}
  \else
    \ifx\@makecaption\@undefined\else
      \caption@InfoNoLine{%
        The definition of \protect\@makecaption\space
        has been changed,\MessageBreak
        frenchb will NOT customize it}%
    \fi
  \fi
}
```

which effectively reverses the claim made in the documentation for `babel-french` (section 1.2.3) that

> When French is not the main language, the colon is preserved for all languages including French [...].

Indeed, if I try changing `\CaptionSeparator` without loading `caption`, the colon is used nonetheless. On the other hand, the change is honored when `caption` is loaded even if `french` is not the main language.

Temporary solution:

```
\renewcommand{\CaptionSeparator}{: }
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't have a github account (never use git), can someone make a bug report on https://github.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/issues

Comment: @daleif Done: https://github.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/issues/9

Comment: URL is now: https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/issues/6